# Unserialize a Dictionary with an Array as Value in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, serialization

in Swift 4 i have an Dictionary with a response from a web server. Inside the Dictionary I have 3 pairs of keys and values. One of that is an array. How can I access the entire array?

When I print

```
print(result["top10"]
```

I get something like this

```
{
    item =     (
                {
            count = 233;
            "engine_size" = "3,0";
            "fuel_type" = Otto;
            "vehicle_brand" = Audi;
            "vehicle_type" = "A4_8K";
        },
                {
            count = 107;
            "engine_size" = "3,0";
            "fuel_type" = Diesel;
            "vehicle_brand" = Audi;
            "vehicle_type" = "A6_4G0";
        };
}
```

I expect the data like:

```
top10[0].count == "223"
top10[0].count == "3,0"

top10[1].count == "107"
top10[1].count == "3,0"
```

and so on

Comment: please include the data that you *expect* to see when you print the result, not only what you are actually getting back

Comment: If you get a `Dictionary` you will have to access it using subscripts (and deal with the consequences (i.e. optionals)). If you would like to read your data as a `struct` (which your 'expected' code seems to indicate) you should learn about the `Codable` protocol and `JSONDecoder` and the like. This is going to get you way closer to what you expect with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is not Top10. Top10 is a dictionary, which contains the "item" list inside it. So, the array you want is actually the "item" array, inside top10 dictionary. And by the print of `result["top10"]`, I can see that `top10["item"]` is an array of dictionaries inside Top10.
Try it like this:

```
if let top10 = result["top10"] as? NSDictionary, let items = top10["item"] as? [NSDictionary] { 
    for item in items {
        print(item["count"])
    }
}
```

It should work :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I´m a step further, but when I us print(item["count"]) I get an error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members.

Comment: Yes, now I can unwrap it with as! String. `if let top10 = result["top10"] as? NSDictionary, let items = top10["item"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                                for item in items {
                                    print(item["count"] as! String)
                                }`